# Crystal Reports - Export report data to XML using custom XML format

Tags: xml, xsd, crystal-reports

I'm looking to build a crystal report and then export the data generated from the report to a specified XML format provided to me in an .xsd file.  I see I can add a new XML Format using a XSL or XSLT file but I'm not sure how to go about structuring these files.  Any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

I tried the general XML export and that didn't get me the desired results.

Comment: Which Crystal Reports version do you use? (I guess your question is not about versions you don't use, but if so then only use the generic [tag:crystal-reports])

Comment: Thanks for the comment, the XML export I'm referring to is supported in all versions of Crystal Reports.